# SQL Server 2014 extended stored procedure gets stuck after Windows Server 2012 R2 updates

Tags: sql-server-2014, windows-server, xp-cmdshell

After running Windows Server updates (including server restart), SQL Server experienced problems executing XP_ commands. These are stuck forever without any response. The only solution I have found so far is to restart the SQL Server services, which is not appropriate in a productive environment.

The operating system is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and the database engine is SQL Server 2014 Standard

Is it possible that Windows Server updates are blocking these extended stored procedures from running?

There are no errors seen in the SQL Server logs related to the problem. I have checked the Windows Event Viewer events and have not found any indication of what may be happening either.

Until now, I have carried out the following actions without positive results:

1. I have updated SQL Server 2014 to the latest patch available today (5029185 Security update for SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU4: October 10, 2023).
2. I have installed a new instance of SQL Server 2014 on the same server, with the latest patches, but the problem is still the same. This makes me think that the problem is with the operating system.

As background, a SQL Server 2017 instance is installed on this same server, which has not been affected. Apparently the problem only affects SQL Server 2014.

Thank you all in advance for your answers or suggestions.

Comment: Are these user-defined XPs?

Comment: No, they are of the style xp_readerrorlog, xp_msver, etc.

Comment: I don't really have any ideas other than move to a supported OS. Windows Server 2012  R2 is end-of-life.

Comment: In addition to what Dan said, SQL Server 2014 is also only a few months away from end of life, and apparently this issue doesn't exist in newer major versions like 2017, as you mentioned. So you should definitely be looking to upgrade SQL Server versions ASAP.

Comment: As a complement to the information, in the organization there are 11 Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL 2014. All of them have been patched and restarted, but only two of them have had the same problem.

Comment: Are these _supported_ and _documented_ extended stored procedures?  Exactly which ones are having a problem?  What are the session wait while executing the proc?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The procedures are xp_readerrorlog, xp_msver and others with xp_. The wait are forever... just rebooting de engine solve the problem.